# Serve nginx's autoindex under different path

Tags: nginx, configuration, directoryindex

I've run into the issue that I would like to enable nginx's autoindex for some directories but those also having their own index files.
So I was wondering if there was a way to make nginx serve it's autoindex page on a different path. Something like `/path/to/dir/autoindex.html`

I tried the following:

```
    location ~* ^/path/to/dir/autoindex.html$ {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_format html; 

        try_files /path/to/dir/ =404;
    }
```

But that strangely just redirects me to `/path/to/dir/` and shows me my default index page.

Additionally I would like to keep this for folders that don't have an index page, just so the path for the autoindex is always consitent.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of a request and what exactly it should serve. It is difficult to see which URL you want to request and what filesystem path autoindex you want to get returned.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `http://example.com/path/to/dir/autoindex.html` should server the auto index of `$webroot/path/to/dir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty decent solution that just cleverly uses redirects and their order:

```
server {
    # listen directives etc...

    root /path/to/web/root/dir;

    # Autoindex only shows when nginx can't file its own index files
    index xxx;

    rewrite ^(?<path>.*)/autoindex\.html$ $path/           last;
    rewrite ^(?<path>.*)/$                $path/index.html last;

    autoindex on;

    # rest of server configuration...
}
```

Only downsite this has is that you can't really use the multiple different index files the `index` directive normally supports. `try_files` can also mess this up, as you need to make sure that for the `<path>/` URI nginx can't find any files so it shows the autoindex.

Wouldn't recommend this on anything but a server or location that servers only static files.

Answer (score 0):

nginx internal rewrite might be applicable here:

```
location /path/autoindex.html {
    rewrite ^ /path/ last;
}

location /path {
    internal; # This location is only used for internal redirects

    autoindex on;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ ^/path {
    ... configure what you want to show with the path
}
```

Comment: Well I was asking about having the auto index page on a different path than one ending in `/`. I know how to enable autoindex

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sadly that returns a 404 for every URI with `/path`. Changing the location to `location = /path/` fixes that part but `/path/autoindex.html` still returns a 404.

Comment: I added a `location` block that handles external requests to `/path`.

Comment: Still 404 for `/path/autoindex.html`

Comment: Even changing the `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ =403;` still returns a 404, telling me that it doesn't seem to hit the other location block.